# regex - counting by unique pattern (HH:MM:__)

Tags: python, regex

i want to count the unique HH:MM:xx(eg. 11:11:00, 11:12:00, 11:12:11) using regex. so far i am only able to count the total of HH:MM:SS in the text. not sure how to continue from here.. this are my codes

```py
pattern = re.compile("(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})") #capture all the pattern with HH:MM:SS
path = r'C:\Users\CL\Desktop\abc.txt'

list1 = [] # to store values in list

for line in open(path,'r'):
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, line): #draw 11:11:00, 11:12:00, 11:12:11
        list1.append(line) #append to a list
   
total = len(list1) #sum list 
print(total) #3
```

sample text

```
11:11:00
abc

11:12:00
abc

11:12:11
abc
```

the desired output should be 2 (unique values - 11:11:xx and 11:12:xx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see below (`data1.txt` is your data)

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(int)
with open('data1.txt') as f:
    lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
    for line in lines:
        if line.count(':') == 2:
            data[line[:5]] += 1
print(data)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'11:11': 1, '11:12': 2})
```

Comment: wow... thank you man interesting... nvr heard of Collection lib before. good stuff

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a set instead of a list?

```
pattern = re.compile("(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})")
path = r'C:\Users\CL\Desktop\abc.txt'

s = set()  # use a set instead of a list, to avoid duplicates

for line in open(path,'r'):
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
        s.add(line[:-3]) #insert into set

total = len(s) #number of elements in s 
print(total) #2
```

This way, if you try to insert an element you've already seen, we won't have multiple copies of it stored, since sets don't allow duplicates.

EDIT: As commented, we are not supposed to include seconds here, which I mistakenly did originally. Fixed now.

Comment: As I understand, the "line" still contains the seconds, so the seconds must be stripped before the value is added to the set.

Comment: Hi, hmm interesting to use Set.. nvr thought of that. is this code supposed to output 2? cause i still see output 3.

Comment: @MikeScotty I misunderstood, edited to fix that.

Comment: @panzers1 I thought you were including the seconds as well, my mistake. It should output 2 now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.findall` here, followed by a list comprehension to remove duplicates:

```py
with open(path, 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
ts = re.findall(r'(\d{2}:\d{2}):\d{2}', data)
res = [] 
[res.append(x) for x in ts if x not in res] 
print(len(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to count the number of occurences you can simply:

```
txtfile = open("C:\Users\CL\Desktop\abc.txt", "r")
filetext = txtfile.read()
txtfile.close()

list1 = set(re.findall("(\d{2}:\d{2}):\d{2}",filetext))

total = len(list1) #sum list
print(total) #3
```

You can use parentheses to specify what you wan to capture (the HH:MM). Then you can use `set` to remove duplicates.